# mysql group by with having

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench, greatest-n-per-group

I have a table like this

```
Ids Part Values
1   1    value1
1   2    value2
2   1    value3
3   1    some other value
4   1    something1
4   2    something else
```

I would like to group by Ids and get values for max(part).

I tried below query -

```
select * from Parts group by Ids having Part = max(Part)
```

But this query is not always returning the values I want.

I want the result as some thing like

```
Ids Part Values
1   2     value2
2   1     value3
3   1     some other value
4   2     something else
```

Can you please help me with the query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this you need to use self join and get the maxima from same table to join

```
select t1.* from Table1 t1
join 
(SELECT MAX(Part) Part ,Ids from Table1 GROUP BY Ids ) t2
on(t1.Ids=t2.Ids and t1.part =t2.Part)
```

### [See fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f8e82/3)